# Change a notification mail sender name in GitLab 11.4.4-ee

Tags: smtp, gitlab, gitlab-ci, mail-sender

I configured GitLab on Google Cloud Platform to send mail. This is the configuration

```
root@mojlab:/home/d# cat /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb
...
nginx['listen_addresses'] = ["0.0.0.0", "[::]"]

gitlab_rails['smtp_enable'] = true
gitlab_rails['smtp_address'] = "smtp.sendgrid.net"
gitlab_rails['smtp_port'] = 587
gitlab_rails['smtp_user_name'] = "du"
gitlab_rails['smtp_password'] = "fakePas$"
gitlab_rails['smtp_domain'] = "smtp.sendgrid.net"
gitlab_rails['smtp_authentication'] = "login"
gitlab_rails['smtp_enable_starttls_auto'] = true
gitlab_rails['smtp_tls'] = false
root@mojlab:/home/d#
```

Mail messages I get are from a `GitLab` address name and the `GitLab` sender name.

[image]

I am trying to change the sender name. I change a file `/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/gitlab.yml` in the line 42 from

```
    email_display_name:
```

to

```
    email_display_name: NewName
```

but after a command `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` the change disappears. The value turns back to blank.

How to change the sender name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do have a `gitlab.rb`, it would be best to try and set that parameter in `gitlab.rb`, not in `gitlab.yml`.
See [this diff for example](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/commit/1da4f5b04fff3d78c453dcea771e44fa5e4948f0).

```
gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_display_name'] = 'Example'
```

Then try the `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` again, which will take into account `gitlab.rb` value.

Comment: Where should I want to implement the command content(gitlab rails) in GitLab? gitlab.rb should be placed in each repository ? right?

Comment: @CyrilI I have never seen `content(gitlab_tails)` implemented. And [`gitlab.rb`](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/configuration.html) is a config GitLab file, not a repository file/